# Referencing an event variable before assignment error and I dont know how to fix it

Tags: python, events, event-handling, pygame, mouseevent

I keep getting this error whenever I try to open the help section:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Chris/Desktop/Paul's stuff/Paul/CpmpProject/Window.py", line 142, in <module>
    game.help()
  File "C:/Users/Chris/Desktop/Paul's stuff/Paul/CpmpProject/Window.py", line 76, in help
    if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'event' referenced before assignment
```

I don't know how to fix this issue. I have a lot of code and I feel that it is a lot to go through to find an error. If you can help me to fix this issue, I will be very grateful and I know a few other people working on similar projects that will be grateful as well as they are having the same issue. My code is below. I don't expect anyone to go through it, but I would be grateful to anyone is willing to and find the error I am having. I have included all of it just in case it is something further up than I expected, but I think the issue is in the help function definition.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

import random
from random import shuffle
back = True
backbutton = pygame.image.load("Back button.png")
helpsection = pygame.image.load("Hunt Help section.png")
class Game():
    def question(self):

        questions = ["What species of bird is also a nickname for New Zealand?",
                     "Which Twins can you play as in Assassin's Creed Syndicate?",
                     "Which year was 'Killing In The Name' Christmas Number one?"]

        answers = [["kiwi", "Kiwi", "Falcon", "Sparrow", "Crow"], ["frye", "Frye", "Bank", "Green", "Bundy"],
                   ["2009", "2009",
                    "1999", "1993",
                    "2004"]]
        # I had to do it in two separate lists as it's easier to work with later on
        # Also I made the correct answers non-case sensitive to make it easier to test.

        Game_back = True

        while Game_back == True:

            r = len(questions)
            score = 0
            s = random.randrange(0, r, 1)
            # This generates a random number within the range of how many questions there are
            # and then prints out that question
            print(questions[s])

            list = answers[s]
            output = []

            for i in range(1, 5):
                output.append(answers[s][i])
            shuffle(output)
            print(output[0] + "     ", output[1] + "     ", output[2] + "      ", output[3])
            # this takes the answers that correspond with the randomly generated question and shuffles the answers
            # I did this as otherwise, the answer would always be the first answer to appear and the player could exploit this

            player_answer = input()

            if player_answer == answers[s][0] or player_answer == answers[s][1]:
                score += 1
                print(score)
            else:
                print("Wrong")
            panswer = input("Would you like to play another round?: ")

            quit = ["Yes", "yes", "Yeah", "yeah"]

            if panswer in quit:
                Game_back = False
            else:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            # this is the basics of the algorithm that will determine if a player can move forward or not in the maze and the score
            # they will have at the end
            ## it takes the input from the player and compares it to the first 2 answers in the corresponding answer set which is
            ## a separate list from the list that is printed out to the player

    def help(self):

        pygame.init()
        self.FPS = 60
        self.fps_clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.surface = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
        # This class sets the basic attributes for the window.
        # The clock is set to 60 and the name of the window
        # is set to The Hunt which is a working title for my project
        DISPLAY_SURF.blit(helpsection, (0, 0))
        DISPLAY_SURF.blit(backbutton, ((640 - 124), (480 - 87)))
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if (640 -124) >= mouse[0] > 640 and (480 - 87) >= mouse[1] > 480:
                back = False
        while True:
            pygame.display.update()
            self.fps_clock.tick(self.FPS)
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()


            # This updates the window display to refresh every clock tick
            # and to set the background colour as white
            # using the RGB colours. I might use these to alter the window's look at a later date





#Initialize pygame and define colours
pygame.init()
white = 255, 255, 255

#Sets the resolution to 640 pixels by 720 pixels and caption for pygame window
DISPLAY_SURF = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 720))
pygame.display.set_caption("The Hunt!")



#Create a clock object
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60

#Define a variable to refer to image
background = pygame.image.load("Startermenu.png")
start = pygame.image.load("PlayGameButton.png")
help = pygame.image.load("HelpButton.png")
credits = pygame.image.load("ShowCreditsButton.png")

Hoveringhelp = pygame.image.load("HoveringHelpButton.png")


#Start main loop
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        DISPLAY_SURF.fill(white)
        DISPLAY_SURF.blit(background, (0, 0))
        DISPLAY_SURF.blit(start, (0, 140))
        DISPLAY_SURF.blit(help, (0, 186))
        DISPLAY_SURF.blit(credits, (0, 235))
        pygame.display.update()
        #if 0 <= mouse[0] < 260 and 180 <= mouse[1] < 230:
         #   DISPLAY_SURF.blit(Hoveringhelp, (0, 186))
          #  print("hovering over help")
        #elif 0 <= mouse[0] < 260 and 235 <= mouse[1] < 270:
         #   print("hovering over credits")
        #elif 0 <= mouse[0] < 260 and 0 <= mouse[1] < 180:
         #   print("hovering over play button")
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if 0 <= mouse[0] < 260 and 140 <= mouse[1] < 180:
                game = Game()
                game.question()
            elif 0 <= mouse[0] < 260 and 180 <= mouse[1] < 230:
                game = Game()
                game.help()
            elif 0 <= mouse[0] < 260 and 240 <= mouse[1] < 285:
                game = Game()
                game.credits()
        elif event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: As the error says, `event` is not defined

Comment: `event` exists only inside `for event` loop.

Answer (score 2):

In the `help()` method:

```
def help(self):

    ...
    if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    ...
    while True:
        ...
        for event in pygame.event.get():
```

`event` is defined in the `for` loop, but you're referring to it *before* that.

One way to fix it is to move the `if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` statement inside the `for` loop.

Or, since `.help()` is only called from the bottom event loop where the event is already known to be `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`, perhaps you could remove the `if` statement altogether?

(BTW, I thought the error message was pretty clear; did you not understand it?)